# Why is numpy.add.at slower than simple grouping and summation?

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I am improving the implementation of my kmeans algorithm and currently have the following ndarrays:

1. Dataset `X` with shape `(n_samples, n_features)` and dtype `np.float64`
2. Labels `y` with shape `(n_samples,)` and dtpye `np.int64`, and it supports to `np.logical_and(0 <= y, y < n_clusters).all()`

Now I need to group the dataset based on labels and calculate the average value to obtain the new cluster centers. To simplify some content, only the summation calculation is performed here. A simple implementation is as follows:

```
new_centers = np.array([X[y == i].sum(0) for i in range(n_clusters)])
```

Note that this requires iterating `n_clusters` times and comparing each time to obtain a mask with a shape of `(n_samples,)`, then copying data from `X` and calculating the sum, and finally stacking them into an array.

I naturally believe that there will be more efficient ways, so I tried using [`numpy.add.at`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
new_centers = np.zeros((n_clusters, n_features))
np.add.at(new_centers, y, X)
```

Here, almost pure C is running without python loops and unnecessary array generation, but surprisingly, under the conditions of `n_clusters, n_samples, n_features = 100, 100_000, 10`, its performance is worse than the naive implementation:

```
In [_]: n_clusters, n_samples, n_features = 100, 100_000, 10

In [_]: rng = np.random.default_rng()
   ...: X = rng.random((n_samples, n_features))
   ...: y = rng.integers(0, n_clusters, n_samples)
   ...:

In [_]: %timeit np.array([X[y == i].sum(0) for i in range(n_clusters)])
29.5 ms ± 852 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [_]: %timeit np.add.at(np.zeros((n_clusters, n_features)), y, X)
58.7 ms ± 708 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I want to know why `numpy.add.at` performed so poorly. As a comparison, I also found two similar methods in `torch` that perform much better than `numpy.add.at` (I have tested that their outputs are very close or the same):

```
In [_]: %%timeit
   ...: new_centers = np.zeros((n_clusters, n_features))
   ...: torch.from_numpy(new_centers).index_put_([torch.from_numpy(y)],
   ...:                                          torch.from_numpy(X), accumulate=True)
   ...:
   ...:
1.74 ms ± 3.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [_]: %%timeit
   ...: new_centers = np.zeros((n_clusters, n_features))
   ...: torch.from_numpy(new_centers).index_add_(0, torch.from_numpy(y), torch.from_numpy(X))
   ...:
   ...:
8.97 ms ± 51.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Some version information:

```
In [_]: sys.version, np.__version__, torch.__version__
Out[_]:
('3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]',
 '1.24.3',
 '2.0.0+cu118')
```

Comment: Did you use a GPU for torch methods?

Comment: @Memristor No, and afaik the numpy array is always on the CPU, so `torch.from_numpy` cannot directly convert it into a tensor on the GPU.

Comment: @Memristor Using GPU on my machine can increase the speed of `Tensor.index_add_` to 120 µs (but there is no significant change in `Tensor.index_put_`).

Comment: I don't know if those libraries use some caching technique, what are the values you get after running, let's say, 3 times each?

Comment: I haven't read the code, but know that `add..at` is slower tjan the equivalent `+=`. It's compiled but has to iterate by index without buffers

Answer (score 1):

[This has been improved](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.25.0-notes.html#ufunc-at-can-be-much-faster) in Numpy's 1.25 version:

> Generic `ufunc.at` can be up to 9x faster. The conditions for this speedup:
>
> - operands are aligned
> - no casting
>
> If ufuncs with appropriate indexed loops on 1d arguments with the above conditions, `ufunc.at` can be up to 60x faster (an additional 7x speedup). Appropriate indexed loops have been added to `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `floor_divide`, `maximum`, `minimum`, `fmax`, and `fmin`.
>
> The internal logic is similar to the logic used for regular ufuncs, which also have fast paths.

I don't have the energy to investigate what optimizations they have made, so this answer may not truly answer the question (unless I had asked "Is there a better way to do it in numpy?" at the time. Unfortunately, I forgot it).

The performance of the same example in the new version has become similar to that of `torch.Tensor.index_add_()` (but `torch.Tensor.index_put_()` is still terrifyingly fast), which is acceptable:

```
In [_]: %timeit np.add.at(np.zeros((n_clusters, n_features)), y, X)
11.5 ms ± 93.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```